# Let bound face-attribute locally

Tags: faces, let-binding

How can I `let-bound` a `face-attribute` locally.
E.g. I want to:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'query-replace nil :background "OrangeRed3")
(perform-replace "bar" "foo" t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

and then restore the default `query-replace` background color. Is the a way to use `let` to do that?

EDIT. I need a solution that will restore the default value even if I quit the command `perform-replace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the attributes of a face are global.  Using `face-remapping-alist` you can make them buffer local, which won't make you happy.

In your case, I would recommend that you define a new face, say `my-performed-replacements` with your preferred background.

When replacing text, you could remap all occurrences of `query-replace` with `my-performed-replacements`.  It would take some non-trivial elisp, but it is certainly doable.

Comment: +1 to the answer and to the question (even if misstated in terms of let binding - that's in fact how the question would naturally be posed).

Comment: +1 I completely agree with your advice, I just wish to point out a technicality. Face attributes are indeed global, but so are all dynamically scoped variables. Against your best advice, they can still be temporarily modified: `(let* ((face 'default) (bg (face-background face))) (set-face-background face "OrangeRed3") (sit-for 2) (set-face-background face bg))`

Comment: @Basil I tried you solution but the problem is that, if I `keyboard-quit` (C-g) the perform-replacement, the default value will not be restored. I need a solution that will restore the default value if I quit the replacement.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I think you can handle that using [`unwind-protect`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cleanups.html), though I haven't tested this and there could be a better way: `(let ((bg ...)) (unwind-protect <body> (set-face-background <face> bg)))`

Comment: @Basil Thank you! This now works fine and does exactly what I need. I think you should write a complete answer to my question. I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I accepted the Lindydancer answer but I also got what I need from Basil's comments. I want to share the solution that fit my needs:

```el
(let* ((face 'query-replace)
       (bg   (face-background face)))
  (set-face-background face "OrangeRed3")
  (unwind-protect
      (perform-replace "bar" "foo" t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))
    (set-face-background face bg)))
```

Comment: If this is what you were after, I'm fine with you accepting this answer instead of mine. (I must admit that I misunderstood the question, I though you were asking for a permanent change for faces inserted in the block.)